# Auto Generate HTML Text inputs based on selection value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a selection with 3 options values . i want to auto generate html input based on selection if user select 2 it show to him two text inputs with same id for both shown.

```
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
```

Comment: Firstly, what have you tried? SO is here to help you debug code not to write it for you. Secondly, `with same id for both shown` that's not possible. `id` attributes *have* to be unique within the DOM.

Comment: i try a java script code the show hidden divs but it's a bad idea

Comment: There doesn't sound like there's anything wrong with that approach

Comment: do you mean you want to auto generate html output based on selection?

Comment: yes i want generate html output based on selection

Comment: I would recommend doing a onchange for the dropdown with the output you want but put a

```
<div hidden>
*your output*
</div>
```
around it and turn the hidden off and on when the change is made

Answer (score 1):

try this  i used jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/rkv88/grym5fqv/

```
On event .change() { 
hide every text input;
for loop N times   N is the option number{
      show that text element  until N index
        }
}
```